# Log errors from Passenger in vhost error.log

Tags: nginx, phusion-passenger

I'm running Phusion Passenger 4.0.40 with nginx.
The server is used to host several websites and each has its own `error.log` file.

However if an application crashes during startup, the error message is not written to the website's `error.log`, rather to global `error.log`. Since global `error.log` is not accessible to the websites, it's hard to debug the issue.

Is there any way to redirect startup errors along with `console.log()` from global `error.log` to website's `error.log`?

Here's the relevant part of nginx config:

```
error_log logs/error.log;

http {
  passenger_friendly_error_pages off;
}

server {
  passenger_enabled on;
  error_log /var/www/subdomain/log/error.log;
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered in the official support forum, this is not currently possible. All stdout/stderr logs are written to the global nginx error log.

Reference: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phusion-passenger/qu01NLqiUlo